# jquery .submit()

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, button, input

Trying to make a validation on form without `<form>` tag.

Its a structure of cms plugin, which uses ajax, don't know why inputs aren't wrapped with `<form></form>`.

Html:

```
<div class="feedback">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="ajax-name" value="Your name" />
    <input id="mail" type="text" name="ajax-mail" value="Your e-mail" />
    <button type="submit" id="done">Send</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".feedback #done").click(function() {
    var flag = true;
    if (!$("#name").val()){
        $("#name").addClass('error');
        flag = false;
    }
    if (flag == true)
        $(".feedback").submit();
});
```

This code doesn't work.

**How do I make validation on form, without `<form>` tag?**

Ajax doesn't know about this validation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than

```
if (flag == true) 
    $(".feedback").submit();
```

do

```
return flag;
```

You can't submit without the `<form>`, but you can prevent or allow the click() even to complete.  Here's the complete code:

```
$(".feedback #done").click(function() { 
    var flag = true; 
    if (!$("#name").val()){ 
        $("#name").addClass('error'); 
        flag = false; 
    }

    //return the value of flag instead of working with submit() 
    return flag;
});
```

If a click event returns false, that should prevent the click from going any further.  Your flag variable will be true or false, depending on how the validation works out, so that will determine if the process moves forward or not.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. Please give more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative way of getting job done, wrap all the child nodes of `.feedback` with a `<form >` tag and then perform `.submit()` on `<form  id="someid">`

```
$(function () {
    $('.feedback').children().wrapAll('<form id="form" />');
    $('.feedback #done').click(function () {
        var flag = true;
        if (!$("#name").val()) {
            $("#name").addClass('error');
            flag = false;
        }
        if (flag) {
            $("#form").submit();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@edit so i actually read the question and even though it's old this still seems relevant...

Just extend the submit button with a .change() or .bind() or .on() if using jQuery 1.7. e.preventDefault() might work with the ajax handler? chain the razzle dazzle unbind function, like so:

```
var some_flag_bool = false;
$('#done').click( function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  some_flag_bool = true;
  $(this).unbind('#done').submit();
  //return might be considered optional
  return this.some_flag_bool;
});
```

or something like this in jQuery 1.7 to try and catch things early:

```
function validation() { if (!foo) { throw new Error("oh noz!"); }
$('body').on('change', 'input', function() { validation(); });
```

could $.attr('disabled','disabled') the button when the document is ready and then $.removeAttr('disabled') in a validation method

but if it were me i'd just call validation methods from my ajax handler or use the jQuery.validation plugin.